# Spring Boot: H2 Not Actually Retrieving From Database

Tags: spring, hibernate, testing, h2

I'm trying to write a simple Repository test in Spring Boot. The Test code looks like this:

```
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    private final TestEntityManager entityManager;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserRepositoryTest(TestEntityManager entityManager, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String firstName = "Frank";
        String lastName = "Sample";
        String email = "frank@example.com";
        String username = "frank@example.com";
        String password = "floople";
        String passwordConfirm = "floople";

        RegisterUserRequest registerUserRequest = new RegisterUserRequest(firstName, lastName, email, username, password, passwordConfirm);
        User user = new User(registerUserRequest);
        user.setSpinsRemaining(0);
        userRepository.save(user);
        userRepository.setSpinsRemainingToTen();
        User found = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        assertThat(found.getSpinsRemaining()).isEqualTo(10);
    }
```

What's I expect to happen is that the new User object is persisted to the database, the row in the database is modified to set spinsRemaining to 10, and then the now-modified row is retrieved from H2 and shoved into a new variable named "found". The "found" variable will point to an instance of a User object with ten spins remaining.

What actually happens is that the "found" variable points to the exact same instance of User that the "user" variable is. In fact, if I modify some property of the "user" variable AFTER persisting it to H2, the resultant "found" object also has the modified property. According to IntelliJ, both "user" and "found" are pointing to the same thing. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate caches entities inside a transaction in memory ("[first level cache](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#architecture-overview)"). - Every time it retrieves an entity from database (or when it's asked to do so by the entity id) it will first look for it in cache so you don't have multiple instances of one entity with the same ID.

But in tests it's [sometimes useful](https://josefczech.cz/2020/02/02/datajpatest-testentitymanager-flush-clear/) to have a "fresh" entity as it can uncover bugs in your persistance configuration/code. What you need to do:

- Call `EntityManager#flush` - this will force synchronization of your changes to the database (`save` method does not guarantee that when called inside a transaction).
- Call `EntityManager#clear` - Hibernate will forget about previous entity instances and will start fetching from DB again.

Alternatively: You can also instruct your Spring repository method to [clear entities automatically after a modifying query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries). - But this will wipe out all entity instances and not only the one you are modifying so it might not be desirable in your application code.

Comment: Calling EntityManager#clear worked out perfectly. Do I need to do the flush and clear in the Repositories I've defined as well, or is this something I only need to do in these tests because I'm interacting with an Entity Manager directly?

Also, I spent hours researching to try to find this answer. What magical Google search phrase would have been a good one to use to find it? If I hadn't known about the Identity Map pattern, is there a way I could have found this answer myself?

Comment: You do not need to call `flush` and `clear` in your code usually - synchronization with DB happens automatically at the end of transaction. But you need to be aware that modifying queries will not affect entities held in memory. Tests are also a bit specific as you want to force update/insert and select queries to be done.

Comment: For the search phrase - unfortunately I'm not sure how to nicely google for that. .o) I would recommend checking how Hibernate handles entities - for example: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-entity-lifecycle and Hibernate docs are also good (albeit long) read. From Hibernate docs: "The Hibernate Session acts as a transaction-scoped cache providing repeatable reads for lookup by identifier and queries that result in loading entities." (Edit: That's actually way better explanation than IM - I will probably edit the answer a bit so it's more precise.)